# Animating word wrap in UILabel during animateAlongsideTransition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a UILabel in a today widget extension that adjust the constraints of during `animateAlongsideTransition`. The UILabel uses `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` which allows for word wrapping when `numberOfLines` is set to 0. My problem is that while the constraints all animate properly, the text inside the UILabel does not change until the animation is finished, resulting in a jump of the text.

Example: UILabel is 100 wide, I animate it to be 130 wide. But the text itself does not fill up that width until the animation is complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try an ugly hack like calling `layoutSubviews` 30 times per second?

Comment: @DepartamentoB I actually never ended up getting this to work. My solution was to have two views, one for each size I wanted to show. During the transition, I moved the two views together, and faded one to alpha 0, the other to alpha 1